# I keep getting the same error no matter what from R library rWBclimate

Tags: r

I am trying to use the package "rWBclimate", but nothing works and I keep getting the same error message.

Even when I try running code from the vignette (see code below) I get the same error

(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rWBclimate/vignettes/rWBclimate.pdf).

I have tried several functions and I have fiddled around with the UTF-settings, I have also updated R and all packages to the latest versions...

```
 library(rWBclimate)

usa.dat <- get_model_temp("USA", "mavg", 2080, 2100)
usa.dat.bcc <- usa.dat[usa.dat$gcm == "bccr_bcm2_0", ]
usa.dat.had <- usa.dat[usa.dat$gcm == "ukmo_hadcm3", ]
usa.dat.bcc$ID <- paste(usa.dat.bcc$scenario, usa.dat.bcc$gcm, sep = "-")
usa.dat.had$ID <- paste(usa.dat.had$scenario, usa.dat.had$gcm, sep = "-")

plot.df <- rbind(usa.dat.bcc, usa.dat.had)
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = as.factor(month), y = data, group = ID, colour = 
gcm, linetype = scenario)) + geom_point() + geom_path() + ylab("Average 
temperature in degrees C \n between
xlab("Month") + theme_bw()
```

Error = "No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in rep(locator, dim(data_out)[1]) : invalid 'times' argument"

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is not the problem here, that is **not** an error message. 
When running vignette this is what pops up for me:

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
>   Error in rep(locator, dim(data_out)[1]) : invalid 'times' argument

The first bit is FYI - R is telling you it  defaults to UTF-8.

Check the description file in the package of for example *tidyverse, ggplot, caret*. You will observe that there is a line reading:
Encoding: UTF-8.

In the description file of the package *rWBclimate* the encoding is missing which I reckon is prompting R's message.

The second bit **is the error** and I suspect the issue is with the package itself as a quick glance shows some of the functions are not visible to R, ie. *check_ISO_codes() returns an error: could not find function "check_ISO_code"*. I am not entirely sure if the code is even maintained anymore, there were some questions about its status:
https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate/issues/35

If I understand correctly the maintenance was shifted but I am not sure if the package has since been updated in any way.

In any case, hope you get to the bottom of this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted a question on Github, and hopefully, they will look into it. I guess it is not being maintained properly..https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate/issues/37