# Right now the package is only installable from github with devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I try to anaylse World Bank climate data using their [rWBclimate](https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate) package. However, no matters what I do, the package is not recognised by my computer. It starts by not completing the first step of the instruction.

`require(rWBclimate)`
results in

> Loading required package: rWBclimate
> Warning message:
> In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
> there is no package called ‘rWBclimate’

and then

> Error in find.package(if (is.null(package)) loadedNamespaces() else package,  :
> there is no package called ‘rWBclimate’

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410514/i-keep-getting-the-same-error-no-matter-what-from-r-library-rwbclimate) case posted, but it doesn't solve my problem

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: You can [install old versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) of the package with `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rWBclimate/rWBclimate_0.1.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")` which should be okay as it seems as if it was removed due to [notes](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/web/checks/2022/2022-06-20_check_results_rWBclimate.html).

Comment: ...  But you will need to make sure that you have all the packages lisyted under [imports](https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L16) **before** trying to install

Comment: It keeps giving me the same error...

Comment: Did you get any error when trying to install? e.g. dd it install correctly or did you get a message on non-zero exit status?

Comment: Finally, I managed to install the package, using @Poiu Rewq recommendation. Now, the problem is that 
```rWBclimate::get_historical_precip(c("USA","BRA","AUS"), "month") ```
returns an error
> Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text. <!doctype html><html lang="en"> (right here) ------^

From what I see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rWBclimate/blob/master/R/get_historical_data.R), the function leads to a non-existing website

Answer (score 0):

To install a package from GitHub you should use `install_github()` function from `devtools` package.

Comment: Thank you. I got through the first step. First, I apologise if my question is too non-advanced. I am now stuck with >Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!doctype html><html lang="en">
                     (right here) ------^

Following some instructions, I already did ```library(jsonlite) # read JSON```

Comment: I don't understand how you got that error and if it's connected to the original question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I followed the steps, according the instructions. My code is:
```devtools::install_github("ropensci/rWBclimate")```
```require(rWBclimate) # world bank package ```
```rWBclimate::get_historical_precip(c("USA","BRA","AUS"), "month") ```

Comment: I can't tell how the fix the error, but the repo is outdated and I doubt it's maintained. You could try redirect your question there